# Random Unfoldings of the Cube

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Motivated by unfoldings of the dodecahedron in [How To Fold It](http://howtofoldit.org/) --
How many (labeled or unlabeled) unfoldings of the 1 x 1 x n stack of unit cubes are there?

---

*JORourke* (4Nov16): John's original image is now lost:
`http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/f3dkg.gif`

*JDM* (11/15/16): The original image is certainly lost from 4 years ago.  Here is a quick example with a 1 × 1 × 1 cube

[image]

---

The dissections of the cube are related to each other by "[hinge](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/gnf/book2.html)" moves (which I've tried to draw).  The graph of unfolding of the cube seems connected by these hinge moves.

---

It's equivalent to consider cutting the cube along the edges.  Then we're looking for [uniform spanning trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_spanning_tree) on the surface of the cube.

*JDM* (11/15/16) I've added some figures of the shapes I was trying to unfold.

[image]

For my  4 (<del>un</del>labeled) (incomplete list of) shapes, **how often do they appear among (uniformly random) unfoldings of the labeled cube??**  *JDM* (11/15/16) *This part of the question is also ambiguous.  I had also been concerned in the 1 × 1 × n case the diagrams are not planar.  David Speyer's answer looks possibly correct.  The graph of unfoldings connected by hinge moves looks non-trivial even in the 1 × 1 × 1 case.)*

Comment: Incidentally, there are exponentially many spanning trees in general: $2^{\Omega(\sqrt{F})}$ for a polyhedron of $F$ faces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be defined by the recursion
$$a_{n+2} + 4 a_{n+1} + a_n =0,\ a_1=-4,\ a_2=15.$$
Let $b_n$ be defined by the recursion
$$b_{n+2} + 6 b_{n+1} + b_n =0,\ b_1 =-6,\ b_2=35.$$

The number of unfoldings of the labeled $1 \times 1 \times n$ cube is $-4 a_n^2 b_n$. (I might have a sign error here.)

We count spanning trees using the [matrix tree theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem). Let $G$ be the dual graph to the $1 \times 1 \times n$ cube (so $G$ has $4n+2$ vertices). Let $V$ be the vector space of functions on the vertices of $G$. Let $\Lambda: V \to V$ be the Laplacian operator. Then $\Lambda$ has a one dimensional kernel -- the constant function -- and we are supposed to compute the coefficient of $t$ in $\det(\Lambda - t \mathrm{Id})$.

The cyclic group of order $4$ acts on the $1 \times 1 \times n$ cube by rotation around the long axis. This action commutes with $\Lambda$. So we can compute $\Lambda$ separately on each of the four eigenspaces of this rotation. The corresponding matrices are
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 1 &-4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 0 & 1 &-4 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 &-4 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &-4 & \cdots & 0 \\
   &   &   &   &   & \ddots &   \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -4 \end{pmatrix} \ \mathrm{on\ the} \pm i \ \mathrm{eigenspace}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-6 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 1 &-6 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 0 & 1 &-6 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 &-6 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &-6 & \cdots & 0 \\
   &   &   &   &   & \ddots &   \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -6 \end{pmatrix} \ \mathrm{on\ the} -1 \ \mathrm{eigenspace}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-4 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 &-2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 &-2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &-2 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &-2 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   &   &   &   &   & \ddots &   \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 4 & -4 \end{pmatrix} \ \mathrm{on\ the}\ 1 \ \mathrm{eigenspace}$$

The first two matrices are invertible and obey the recursions $a_n$ and $b_n$ respectfully. (See the recursive formula displayed in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix).)

The last matrix has a one dimension kernel. Taking the cofactor by deleting the last row and column, one gets a matrix whose determinant is $-4$, as can be checked from the same recursion as above.

Putting it all together, the number of spanning trees is $-4 a_n^2 b_n$.

I don't understand the statistical question you want to ask about the unfolded shapes.

---

**Remark:** Using the cyclic symmetry broght this computation down into the range of reasonable computation. But, even without that, I immediately knew that the answer would obey some linear recursion. Consider building a spanning tree of $G$ one layer at a time as we travel along the long axis of the cube. At the $k$-th partial stage, there are $4$ vertices of $G$ on the exposed boundary; call them $u_k$, $v_w$, $w_v$, $x_k$. The graph so far is a forest, each connected component of which contains at least one of the four exposed vertices. There are $15$ ways to group these $4$ vertices into connected components, one of which is actually impossible for planarity reasons. So there is some $14 \times 14$ matrix which records, for example, if the vertices on one level are grouped as $(\{ u_k, v_k \}, \{ w_k \}, \{ x_k \})$, how many ways are there to extend the forest to one where the vertices on the next level are grouped as $( \{ u_{k+1} \}, \{ v_{k+1},  w_{k+1}, x_{k+1} \})$. Taking powers of this $14 \times 14$ matrix and then pairing with some row and column vectors to handle end effects, you get this count.

This is what I learned to call the "transfer matrix method" (although Wikipedia seems to call something else by that name) and it solves almost all "linear" combinatorics problems.

Comment: So this is how you use matrix-tree! I will think about how to modify your answer to the labeled case & how to make my statistics question more precise.

Comment: Impressive analysis! I would just like to verify that if $n=1$, your formula yields $−4(−4)^{2}(−6)=384$, and indeed there are 384 unfoldings of the cube (and the regular octahedron), obviously many of them congruent as geometric objects. 

Comment: we found 11 different shapes and I wanted to know how often each appears among the 384.  they are related to each other by hinge moves and i bet you can have a markov chain out of them.

Comment: You actually just want to know the answer for $n=1$? I assumed your question was meant to make sense as $n \to infty$, which is why I didn't understand it. If you just want the count for $n=1$, I don't see anything to do more clever that making a program to count them.

Comment: as phrased, my question doesn't make sense for n > 1, right?  the real story goes I was talking with a student about O'Rourke's small book and we looked at the page on unfoldings of the dodecahedron.  I felt this was too complicated so I worked with the cube.  I notice it was equivalent to finding spanning trees on the cube.  So uniform unfoldings $\leftrightarrow$ uniform spanning trees on graphs on $S^2 \leftrightarrow$ loop-erased walk on $S^2$.  But what about them and we have just the cube?

Comment: There are some very interesting charts on loop-erased walk by Kenyon/Wilson '11 http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1107.3377 and I noticed many probabilities are expanded in powers of $\frac{1}{\pi}$ and I wondered what that was about.  They seem to be counting frequencies of "motifs" (for lack of a better word) in uniform spanning trees.  I came up with the $1 \times 1 \times n$ problem to try to understand this better.

Comment: @John: It may be wise to stay away from the dodecahedron at first: 5,184,000 unfoldings but only 43,380 noncongruent shapes!

Comment: Perhaps one could use Burnside's Lemma to count how the 384 unfoldings map down to the 11 noncongruent shapes? If so, this might generalize to $1 \times 1 \times n$ ...

Comment: Joseph O'Rourke: does that include unfoldings with sides overlapping in the plane?  I don't even know whether the dodecahedron has such unfoldings.  


Comment: @Zsbán: Good question, but in fact no edge-unfolding (cutting along edges) of a Platonic solid overlaps in the plane.  Long believed; recently settled. But as soon as one extends to Archimedian solids, overlap does occur.

Comment: Joseph O'Rourke: thanks for the answer.


Comment: Is the sequence now in OEIS?

Answer (score 12):

Not an answer; just a remark: 
Your inventory of the unfoldings of the $1 \times 1 \times 1$ cube is missing two unfoldings:
there are 11.

           
[image: Cube Nets]

      
<sub>(Figure from *[How To Fold It: The Mathematics of Linkages, Origami, and Polyhedra](http://www.cambridge.org/us/knowledge/isbn/item6015150/How%2520to%2520Fold%2520It/?site_locale=en_US)*, p.166)</sub>