# Tiling space with supertile of hypercube unfoldings

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, polyhedra, tiling

Two students in my class
asked and answered what might be a novel question.
It is well known that the cube has exactly $11$ edge-unfoldings
(or "nets"), as shown below:

[image]

(Image from [this MO posting](https://mathoverflow.net/a/86349/6094).)

It is also well known that each of the eleven can tile the plane,
i.e., form a *monohedral* tiling.
The students,
Elsa Bieger and Heather Robertson,
asked: Can the $11$ unfoldings be edge-to-edge glued together, each used
exactly once, to form a *supertile* that can then tile the plane
monohedrally?
They found four supertiles:

[image: Supertiles]

and here's how each supertile fits together with copies of itself:

[image: Monohedral]

So in the spirt of the earlier MO question,
[Which unfoldings of the hypercube tile 3-space](https://mathoverflow.net/q/199097/6094),
which led to
[Moritz Firsching showing](https://mathoverflow.net/a/392828/6094)
that all hypercube unfoldings can
(individually) tile space,
it is natural to ask:

> ***Q***. Can the
> [$261$ unfoldings of the hypercube](https://mathoverflow.net/q/198722/6094)
> be face-to-face glued together, each used
> exactly once, to form a supertile that can then tile $3$-space
> monohedrally?

Comment: Note that all four supertiles satisfy the [Conway criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_criterion) for tiling the plane, which prompts the obvious question as to whether there's a version of the criterion that applies in three dimensions; I feel like answering that question is a good (if hardly necessary) step towards answering this one.